# Chatterbot Giving SpaCy Key Error / Adapter Issue

Tags: python, spacy, chatterbot

I’m trying to develop a chatterbot that can respond to both “matching” type input and computational and time input.
While running follow script

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot(
'Maxine',
storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
logic_adapters=[
'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'
],
database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
)

print('ask me something')
while True:
try:
bot_input = bot.get_response(input())
print(bot_input)

except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
    break
```

Get following responses

```
ask me something
how are you
I am good.
```

Which is correct
But then:

how much is 2 + 2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "maxine.py", line 17, in 
bot_input = bot.get_response(input())
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/chatterbot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 114, in get_response
response = self.generate_response(input_statement, additional_response_selection_parameters)
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/chatterbot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 150, in generate_response
output = adapter.process(input_statement, additional_response_selection_parameters)
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/chatterbot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/logic/best_match.py", line 61, in process
input_statement.text
File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/chatterbot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 45, in get_bigram_pair_string
tokens[index].lemma_.lower()
File "token.pyx", line 894, in spacy.tokens.token.Token.lemma_.get
File "strings.pyx", line 136, in spacy.strings.StringStore.getitem
KeyError: "[E018] Can't retrieve string for hash '471611514'. This usually refers to an issue with the Vocab or StringStore."
```

```
`I am running this on a RPi4 with this version of SpaCy
spaCy version 2.3.2
Location /home/pi/.virtualenvs/chatterbot/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy
Platform Linux-5.4.51-v7l+-armv7l-with-debian-10.4
Python version 3.7.3
Models en
```

Also if i comment out the BestMatch Adapter I get:

```
python maxine.py
ask me something
how much is 2 + 2
2 + 2 = 4
what time is it
The current time is 05:02 PM
how are you
The current time is 05:02 PM
```

Which seems to mean bestMatch is taking precedence of the the other adapters

Answer (score 0):

I changed my architecture to arm64 and it seems to be working now.
BTW still needed to install spacy using
BLIS_ARCH="generic" pip3 install --user spacy --no-binary=blis